# StreamWriter.close() does not flush in Windows 2012

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012, flush

I'm coding a VB.net application that writes files on disk. I have to be sure data is really written on disk every 1 second. So I close the stream, set the last write date and reopen it:

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
streamer.Close()
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, now)
streamer = File.AppendText(path)
```

This works without problem under Windows 7. Under Windows Server 2012, last write date is updated, but file size is not updated. It seems that OS cache is not really flushed.

I tried with `Flush`, `Close` and `Using`, without success. I also tried to limit the OS cache using [SetSystemFileCacheSize.exe](http://www.microimages.com/downloads/SetFileCacheSize.htm), but nothing. Also the use of the latest framework, 4.6.2, makes no difference. Don't really know what to do to force the flush.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: You should be using a `Using` block. After the using block, dispose will be called...which will flush and close the stream for you.

Comment: @Zaggler: can't do `Using`. Files are updated every one second, but the function that do the write is called about every 20ms. Furthermore the function is called after a TCP/IP incoming data, so it's not predictable when I have to flush.

Comment: that´s not a reason why you can´t use `Using`. Btw...why not call the function every second?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like buffering the data and then writing it every second would be a better option.

Comment: @AlexB. because I have to avoid the memory overflow. I get a lot of data from more than 300 sources every 20 ms, so I write it on file as fast as I can.

Comment: Anyway, for what I know, `Using` calls `Close()` inside a try-catch statement. I don't think it will solve my problem.

Comment: `but file size is not updated` - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813/ might be relevant.